# Pulling images from a MongoDb database

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a method that on click produces an excel file with information in it. I have been asked to pull images from the data base and add them within the excel file as well. This is how I am pulling the images:

```
 ProductImages = new List<ProductImageAndMeta>();
                var flyerBlocks = await FlyerBlockRepository.FindAllInAllPageByFLyerIdAsync(selectedFlyer.Id);
                var ComposerDataImages = await ComposerDataFilesRepo.GetAllFlyerImages(FlyerId);

                foreach (var ComposerDataImage in ComposerDataImages)
                {
                    var ProductImage = new ProductImageAndMeta();
                    ProductImage.Id = ObjectId.Parse(ComposerDataImage.Id);
                    Stream stream = await ComposerDataFilesRepo.OpenDataAsync(ComposerDataImage.Filename);
                    ProductImage.Image = await BaseBarParser.ConvertToMemoryStram(stream);
                    ProductImage.Filename = ComposerDataImage.Filename;
                    ProductImage.metadata = ComposerDataImage.metadata;
                    ProductImages.Add(ProductImage);
                }
```

This is my GetAllFlyerImages method:

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<ComposerDataFiles>> GetAllFlyerImages(string FlyerId)
        {
            //var filter = Builders<ComposerDataFiles>.Filter.Empty;
            //return (await Collection.FindAsync(filter)).ToList();
            var filter = Builders<GridFSFileInfo>.Filter.Where(f => f.Metadata["flyerId"] == FlyerId && f.Metadata["type"] == "ProductImage");
            var dataRecords = await FindDataAsync(filter);

            var results = dataRecords.ToList();
            List<ComposerDataFiles> images = new List<ComposerDataFiles>();

            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                var image = new ComposerDataFiles();
                image.Id = result.Id.ToString();
                image.Filename = result.Filename;
                image.metadata = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<ComposerDataFilesMetadata>(result.Metadata);
                images.Add(image);
            }
            return images;
        }
```

This is my Open DataAsyncMethod:

```
  public async Task<GridFSDownloadStream> OpenDataAsync(string filename)
        {
            var file = await FindOneDataAsync(filename);
            if (file == null)
                return null;
            return await _bucket.OpenDownloadStreamAsync(file.Id);
        }
```

ProductImageAndMetaClass:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CTCDigital.InDesign.Models.Flyer
{
    public class ProductImageAndMeta
    {
        public MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId? Id { get; set; }
        public string Filename { get; set; }
        public MemoryStream Image { get; set; }
        public ComposerDataFilesMetadata metadata { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure where my slowdown occurs is the foreach being used to add one product image at a time. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to make it quicker though. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `flyerBlocks` is not used in the current in the current code. did you remove the related code ?

Answer (score 4):

### Some quick remarks:

- Your code uses inconsistent capitalization, which often does not follow [Microsoft's guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions).
- Don't needlessly abbreviate: why use "repo" in `ComposerDataFilesRepo` instead of "repository"?
- The whole `foreach (var ComposerDataImage in ComposerDataImages)` block could be done as a `.Select()` on `ComposerDataImages` by using a second method that accepts a `ComposerDataImage` as a param and returns a `ProductImage`. Same with the `foreach (var result in results)` code, BTW.
- `var dataRecords = await FindDataAsync(filter);` and `var results = dataRecords.ToList();` can be done in a single line, plus then you don't need to then use the nondescriptive "results".
- A class name should almost never be a plural: `ComposerDataFiles`.
- `GetAllFlyerImages` returns `IEnumerable<ComposerDataFiles>` which get called `ComposerDataImages` in your first code block. To me, this is confusing. Is it a `FlyerImage`? A `ComposerDataFile`? A `ComposerDataImage`?
- Why is it called `ProductImageAndMeta`? Is there already a `ProductImage` class?

Honestly, this code feels unpolished and rough.

---

As for the performance: yes, having to open a stream for each image etc. can become expensive, but it is nearly impossible for us to know where the bottleneck is. How many images are involved? How big is each image? How are they stored? Etc.